# Redirect my Git App to User's Slack for permission to post

Tags: git, oauth, slack, slack-api

I am very new at creating APIs and I am trying to understand how OAuth works.

I am trying to make a Github App that redirects to User's Slack, on installation. The redirection happens to take permission from the user to post on their channel.

I have done a little research, and I found out that I can use https://slack.com/oauth/authorize?scope=&client_id= to request access from the user.

But my main doubt is, how will I know the client_id?

Answer (score 0):

Ever Slack app has a client ID and client secret. So to "get" the client ID you need to create your own Slack app.

See here for details. https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth

Comment: What if the user installing my Git App doesn't have my Slack app installed? (sorry if its a dumb quesiton)

Comment: Then it won't work. Alternatively you could ask users to provide a webhook URL for their Slack so your Git App could post to it.

Comment: I was trying to do something like, when 3rd party apps/websites ask you to login via google/facebook. Imitating that scenario, the scenario doesn't need to have my Slack App but just a slack account.

Comment: Sure you can sign in with a Slack account jut like with google. But that will not give your app access to the users workspace.